# Postgresql-simple and values of PostgreSQL-specific types

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I would like to work with some the database-specific datatypes like money, point, inet, etc. It is possible to insert them as strings. However, I could not find an example of how to fetch them since they are not in the list passed to FromField.mkCompats function.

When I try to fetch such a value, there is an exception

```
*** Exception: Incompatible {errSQLType = "money", errHaskellType = "Text", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
```

Is there a way to do this not resorting to the low-level postgresql-libpq?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  postgresql-simple can do this!  However, previously this was not well documented.   Check out the example code in the [FromField module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/postgresql-simple/0.3.3.2/doc/html/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html).

What you can do is define a type for representing Money, (e.g. a newtype for Text)  and then defining a `FromField` instance that provides the appropriate conversion.  A canonical conversion would first check the type,  then check if the data is not null,  and finally attempt to perform the conversion.  Since money is a built-in type provided by postgresql proper,  it has a stable type OID and for typechecking purposes all you need to do is to use the `typeOID` function.

In cases where the type is provided by an extension to postgresql,  the type OID can vary from database to database.   In this case,  I recommend using the `typename` function to get the string which does not vary.

Unfortunately,  it is not (yet?) possible to add conversions to existing `FromField` instances from additional postgresql types.

(Sorry for the late reply, I don't normally visit Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about haskell, but, you should be able to just typecast the values in the query.  Such as:

```
 select your_money_field::text from your_table;
```

Again, I don't know how you are querying...  if you are using some kind of ORM then you might not be able to do this.